# BeautifulSoup find a data-reactid

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a python script using beautifulsoup to scrape a property sales website. 
I am trying to get the number of beds from the HTML.

The data-reactid changes for each listing in the search results. The number $11606747 is unique. 
I am trying to wild card search for "*$beds.0.0" to return the number of beds =3 in the example.

There is no error message, and the code runs but doesn't return the number.

What am I doing wrong?

The HTML:

```
<div class="property-features is-regular listing-result__features" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2"><span class="property-feature__feature" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds"><span class="property-feature__feature-text-container" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0"><span data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.0">3</span><span data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.1"> </span><span class="property-features__feature-text" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.2">Beds</span></span>
```

The Python code

```
beds = listing.findAll('span',{"data-reactid":re.compile('*$beds.0.0')})
```

Comment: See the edited code. I've already updated it. I think the output you wanted is `3 Beds`. However, you tried to edit your post but it stills doesn't bring the clarity about your required output. Try to be explicit in your next posts @ Mark Walters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this to get the bed status:

```
content='''
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="property-features is-regular listing-result__features" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2">
   <span class="property-feature__feature" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds">
    <span class="property-feature__feature-text-container" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0">
     <span data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.0">
      3
     </span>
     <span data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.1">
     </span>
     <span class="property-features__feature-text" data-reactid=".1e881obdfqe.3.1.3.1:$11606747.0.1.0.2.$beds.0.2">
      Beds
     </span>
    </span>
   </span>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
'''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
item = soup.select("div span[data-reactid*='$11606747']")[0].text
print(' '.join(item.split()))
```

Result:

```
3 Beds
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape symbols `$`, `.` and `*`, because they are special in regex:

```
re.compile(r'\*\$beds\.0\.0')
```

Comment: this is still returning an empty list:
print beds gives []